Why does everyone have a bleeding nose apart from Stan Edgar in "The Boys" S04E05?
In The Boys, season 4, episode 5, why does everyone have a bleeding nose apart from Stan Edgar?
Butcher convinces Stan Edgar that they need to unite against Neuman.
After they return to Stan Edgar's residence, they discover Neuman has converted it into a lab, where blood paints the floor and walls, experiment subjects explode into pieces, etc.
Suddenly, Neuman returns, and everyone on The Boys team, apart from Stan Edgar, starts having blood running out of their noses.
What is the reason behind their bleeding noses? Why doesn't Stan Edgar have a bleeding nose?

The nosebleeds in this scene are a clear indicator of Victoria Neuman's presence and her use of powers. This isn't the first time we've seen this effect—it's a recurring theme throughout both The Boys and its spin-off series Gen V.
As revealed in Gen V, Neuman's ability is blood manipulation, which explains how she can make people's heads explode. In this particular scene, she's causing everyone's noses to bleed as a warning to The Boys.
Interestingly, Stan Edgar doesn't experience a nosebleed. This could be because Neuman, his adoptive daughter, is deliberately sparing him from her power's effects.
So, when you see those nosebleeds, it's basically the show's way of saying, "Heads up! Victoria Neuman is nearby and flexing her powers."

I see, I was suspecting it was some kind of directional virus at play.
